# I implemented my own hash table in java,but I need to remove object using value not key

Tags: java, hash, key, hashtable

In own hash table in java,but I need to write a function remove object using value not key.So please help me.And I also need to check a particular value exists in the table or not in a separate function.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class LinkedHashEntry 
{
     String key;
     int value;
     LinkedHashEntry next;

     LinkedHashEntry(String key, int value) 
     {
          this.key = key;
          this.value = value;
          this.next = null;
     }
}
class HashTable
{
     private int TABLE_SIZE;
     private int size; 
     private LinkedHashEntry[] table;

     public HashTable(int ts) 
     {
         size = 0;
         TABLE_SIZE = ts;
         table = new LinkedHashEntry[TABLE_SIZE];
         for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
             table[i] = null;
     } 
     public int getSize()
     {
          return size;
     }
     public void makeEmpty()
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
              table[i] = null;
     }
     public int get(String key) 
     {
         int hash = (myhash( key ) % TABLE_SIZE);
         if (table[hash] == null)
              return -1;
         else 
         {
             LinkedHashEntry entry = table[hash];
             while (entry != null && !entry.key.equals(key))
             entry = entry.next;
             if (entry == null)
                 return -1;
             else
                  return entry.value;
         }
     }
     public void insert(String key, int value) 
     {
          int hash = (myhash( key ) % TABLE_SIZE);
          if (table[hash] == null)
              table[hash] = new LinkedHashEntry(key, value);
          else 
          {
               LinkedHashEntry entry = table[hash];
               while (entry.next != null && !entry.key.equals(key))
               entry = entry.next;
               if (entry.key.equals(key))
                     entry.value = value;
               else
                    entry.next = new LinkedHashEntry(key, value);
          }
          size++;
      }

      public void remove(String key) 
      {
          int hash = (myhash( key ) % TABLE_SIZE);
          if (table[hash] != null) 
          {
              LinkedHashEntry prevEntry = null;
              LinkedHashEntry entry = table[hash];
              while (entry.next != null && !entry.key.equals(key)) 
              {
                  prevEntry = entry;
                  entry = entry.next;
              }
              if (entry.key.equals(key)) 
              {
                  if (prevEntry == null)
                      table[hash] = entry.next;
                  else
                      prevEntry.next = entry.next;
                      size--;
              }
          }
      }
      private int myhash(String x )
      {
            int hashVal = x.hashCode( );
            hashVal %= TABLE_SIZE;
            if (hashVal < 0)
                  hashVal += TABLE_SIZE;
            return hashVal;
      }
      public void printHashTable()
      {
           for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
           {
                   System.out.print("\nBucket "+ (i + 1) +" : ");
                   LinkedHashEntry entry = table[i];
                   while (entry != null)
                   {
                         System.out.print(entry.value +" ");
                         entry = entry.next;
                   }            
           }
      }
}
public class Hash_tab
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Hash Table Test\n\n");
             System.out.println("Enter size");

             HashTable ht = new HashTable(scan.nextInt() );

             char ch;

             do    
             {
                  System.out.println("\nHash Table Operations\n");
                  System.out.println("1. insert ");
                  System.out.println("2. remove");
                  System.out.println("3. get");            
                  System.out.println("4. clear");
                  System.out.println("5. size");

                  int choice = scan.nextInt();            
                  switch (choice)
                  {
                     case 1 : 
                     System.out.println("Enter key and value");
                     ht.insert(scan.next(), scan.nextInt() ); 
                     break; 

                     case 2 :                 
                     System.out.println("Enter key");
                     ht.remove( scan.next() ); 
                     break;                        

                     case 3 : 
                     System.out.println("Enter key");
                     System.out.println("Value = "+ ht.get( scan.next() )); 
                     break;                                   

                     case 4 : 
                     ht.makeEmpty();
                     System.out.println("Hash Table Cleared\n");
                     break;

                     case 5 : 
                     System.out.println("Size = "+ ht.getSize() );
                     break;         

                     default : 
                     System.out.println("Wrong Entry \n ");
                     break;   
                 }

                 ht.printHashTable();  

                 System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
                 ch = scan.next().charAt(0);                        
             } while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');  
       }
}
```

Comment: Hash tables are key-based data structures - the value is basically irrelevant to its structure. If you want to remove by value, you've got to iterate all of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only efficient way you can do is- maintain another mapping of `<value, List<Keys>>`. When you need to remove any value, remove the entries related to all those keys maintained in the other table.

Otherwise there is no escape from full scan.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables do not work that way. Getting (and therefore deleting) a value with its key is what Hashtables are for.
(I am unable to see how you implemented your Hashtable, I guess it is an array).
You have to iterate through the array and delete

- all
- the first occurrence

Again: A Hashtable might be either the wrong Structure or used false. Either Switch key and value (which is possible for multiple values as well).
Your `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` will be a `HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>`, but as you need it that way.

PS: At least in Java 8 it is 'easy' to do with the built-in Hashmap ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-))

Comment: I understand your point.But I am bound to not to use the built in hashmap...I need to build my own hash table